# Remove QuerySet format from Output

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How do I remove queryset from the output?

MY Query format

```
     Xname= final.objects.filter(fshape=shapeofpill).values('fnmae')
     XDescr= final.objects.filter(fshape=shapeofpill).values("fdescr")
     return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', {'Xname':Xname, 'XDescr':XDescr})
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [{'fnmae': 'Dexmethylphenidate'}]>
<QuerySet [{'fdescr': 'Dexmethylphenidate is used in the treatment of adh'}]>
```

I want only values eg. In first query I want only Dexmethylphenidate as a Output

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the values (and not the name key) you can use a flat `values_list` and wrap it in a `list()`

```
Xname = list(final.objects.filter(fshape=shapeofpill).values_list('fnmae', flat=True))
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you for helping me. After modifying the above corrections now I got Output like :    <QuerySet ['Dexmethylphenidate']>

Comment: @Vinayak are you wrapping the call in a `list()` method? This should force the type to a normal python list.